# Dynamically resize image pyGTK (python)

Tags: python, image, resize, gtk, pygtk

I'm stuck on the problem i don't understand. Main program runs from

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    HelloWorld()
    gtk.main()
```

inside `HelloWorld` class i have two signals:

```
self.button.connect("file-set", self.load_image)
self.window.connect("check-resize", self.resize_image)
```

and here they are:

```
def load_image(self, widget):
    self.image_loc = self.button.get_filename()
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(self.image_loc)

    self.resize_image
    print "image loaded"
```

and

```
def resize_image(self, widget):
    allocation = self.scrolledwindow.get_allocation()
    win_h = float(allocation.height)
    win_w = float(allocation.width)
    wk = round(float(win_h / win_w), 6)

    if self.image_loc is not None:
        pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(self.image_loc)

        image_h = float(pixbuf.get_height())
        image_w = float(pixbuf.get_width())
        ik = round(float(image_h / image_w), 6)

        if image_h <= win_h and image_w <= win_w:
            pixbuf = pixbuf.scale_simple(int(image_w), int(image_h), gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
        elif (image_h > win_h and image_w <= win_w) or (image_h > win_h and image_w > win_w and ik >= wk):
            pixbuf = pixbuf.scale_simple(int((win_h - 30) * (1 / ik)), int(win_h) - 30, gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
        elif (image_h <= win_h and image_w > win_w) or (image_h > win_h and image_w > win_w and ik < wk):
            pixbuf = pixbuf.scale_simple(int(win_w) - 30, int((win_w - 30) * ik), gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
        else:
            print "WTF? Incorrect image size calculation"
        self.image.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)

    print "window resized"
```

While loading image goes fine and resize is ok, i need to `Ctrl+C` each time i resize the window. Why? As i've found, the problem is localized inside `set_from_pixbuf()` method because if i remove it, i get "image loaded" and "window resized" prints without loop.
Traceback:

```
window resized
window resized
image loaded
window resized
[...lots of prints...]
window resized
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./photgal.py", line 229, in resize_image
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(self.image_loc)
KeyboardInterrupt
window resized
[...lots of prints...]
window resized
window resized
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./photgal.py", line 229, in resize_image
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(self.image_loc)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

**Update**
from [this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2000-October/msg00210.html) source :`You can easily get into infinite loops doing this type
of thing though.` which is my case as i understand, suggestion is `The "right way" to` resize one widget while another was resized `is usually to write a custom container
widget that sizes things the way you want.`. How to write this container?

Comment: The accepted answer no longer has the information to resolve this - any chance you can post the answer you used to resolve this please?

Comment: Sorry, old thread, no working code left. Try something like this: https://github.com/onyxfish/ration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resize_image() is a infinate loop. Because if window receives `check-resize` signal, `resize_image()` is called, and image is rerendered, and another `check-resize` signal is emited again....

So we need some tricks to break that.

I've written a small demo app, here, https://github.com/LiuLang/gtk-test/tree/master/resize-image, which solves this problem.